# Prove that $|x^a-y^a| \le |x-y|^a$ $if$ $0\le a \le 1 $, $0\le x$ $and$ $0\le y$.

Tags: inequality

I found this inequality in a test, and while it was easy to prove it if a = 1/2, I didn't manage to prove it for $0\le a \le 1 $.
I know that this proof as nothing to do with the triangle inequality, in fact the problem is nearly identical if we suppose that $0\le y \le x $. 
I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please explain inequality $|x^{p}-y^{p}| \leq |x-y|^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10993/please-explain-inequality-xp-yp-leq-x-yp)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2699594/42969.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'am sorry that I asked the same question, but I'am new to this platform and I can't quite navigate with ease in it. Next time I will search better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $x\ge y$. Dividing both sides by $y^a$ and taking all terms to the right, we want to show that
$$f(z)=(z-1)^a-z^a+1\ge0\quad\forall z>1$$
$\left(\text{where }z=\dfrac xy\right)$Differentiating with respect to $z$, we get,
$$f'(z)=a(z-1)^{a-1}-az^{a-1}\ge0\quad\forall z>1$$
(since $a-1\le0$). Also,
$$f(1)=0$$
Therefore, $f$ is a monotonic increasing function with $1$ as a root. Hence, it takes positive values $\forall z>1$ and we are done.